# Is there any existing tag-lib with token-tag built in form-tag

Tags: struts2, freemarker

For passing XSRF token with Struts2 forms, I have to put the token tag inside all forms. The baseline jsp in tiles-def can't have an all-encompassing form.

Have you ever extended the form tag to include token tag by default or know of some library that does that?

I haven't explored Freemarker template, so do not know if this is feasible or not. If there are no existing solution, I'll try to build my own.

Comment: Just edit `<s:form>` tag template to include token.

Comment: Thanks Aleks. Including token in the form template didn't work out, as token-template didn't get the required token attributes in request. The tag s:token is required to generate the token attribute.

Comment: What do you mean by *token-template didn't get the required token attributes in request*? Maybe you can post the code that you have and ask a specific question about errors you got.

Comment: In the hindsight, and it struck rather late for my purpose, I see the "<@s." use in the template files. I'll update once I find out if adding "<@s.token/>" in form template invokes the tag class as well as include the token tag's template in current template.

Comment: Aleksandr, I started by copying the content of token.ftl directly into form-close.ftl. I think, I should have added "<@s.token/>". I am trying that now.

Comment: Yes, you should use `<@s.token/>` instead of just copying template content.

Comment: Works like a charm :-). My custom form-close template looks like this : <@s.token/>
<#include "/${parameters.templateDir}/xhtml/form-close.ftl" />

Comment: You could answer (and mark it as accepted answer) your own question for future visitors with similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To consolidate from the comments section,

1) Create a new theme

2) Extend "form-close.ftl" to this

```
<@s.token/>
<#include "/${parameters.templateDir}/xhtml/form-close.ftl" />
```

Add `tokenSession` (or `token`) interceptor in your stack.

With these changes, all struts forms will have a struts-token added without specifying `<s:token>` in each of them.